# Use ACS Management Service via c# to reimport Metadata on IdP

Tags: c#, azure, umbraco, acs

I'm working on a project involving ADFS2.0, Azure ACS and Umbraco CMS.

When we create a new website, and add it to Relying Party Applications, and add an Identity Provider in Azure, it's supposed to push the settings to Umbraco CMS also.

However, this connection to Umbraco does not seem to work. It can't import the Identity Provider, unless I manually go into Azure, and reimport Metadata from WS-Federation.
Then the IdP is pushed to Umbraco also.

This reimport, I would like to do from my C# project, but can't seem to find the possibility ind the API

Is there some kind of explanation to this, and a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is whether there is a way to programmatically import federation metadata for an identity provider in ACS. In that case, the answer is yes, this is supported.

Make an HTTP POST to the following URL:
https://[namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/mgmt/service/importFederationMetadata/ImportIdentityProvider

The contents of this request must be:

- A management service token in the Authorization header (see [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185905.aspx))
- An HTTP Header "metadataUrl" that includes the URL where the metadata
  came from
- A POST body containing the metadata of the identity provider.

Comment: Yes that sounds kinda like what im looking for. Will try and see if it does the trick.

Does it work on an already existing IdentitiProvider?